# Spatial Results - Geometry/Geography DataTypes C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, geometry, geography

Is it possible to display Spatial Results as per SQL Server (Geometry & Geography) data types in a Window within Visual Studio?  Currently I utilise Visual Studio 2010 - Does anything like this run under later versions of V.S.  Eg. 2012/2014?

It would be great if there was a special tool (utilising the toolbox) to handle these data-types - like a spatial results equivalent window to a data-grid view.

Thanks
Scott.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about What does a toolbox have to do with spatial data types?? What do you `really` need to do, specifically? Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: I need to display a Map with Lines and Points in a C# development program (utilising Visual studio), which will display as per the Spatial Results window in SQL Server.

Comment: "a C# program" - C# is just a language. What platform are you using? ASP.Net Webforms? ASP.Net MVC? XBox? Unity3D? Silverlight? WinRT? WPF? winforms? Android? Please be clear and specific.

Comment: By the way... [**What Have You Tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I am currently utilising ASP.Net Webforms, on a Windows Client, utilising DB Server: SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2010.  Sorry for not being so clear.

Comment: I have edited your tags.

Comment: Spatial results are to be displayed on a map. Spatial data represents "thing" on a map, a point, a line, a surface. In SQL Server Management Studio it's just a grid with coordinates. To display your spatial results you should use an API like ESRI ArcGis For WPF, SharpMap...

Comment: Thanks FloChanz,  It looks like ArcGis seems to be the best option.  I just thought that Microsoft may have embedded an API in later versions of Visual Studio.